# How to fetch a list of items from database row and return a list in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database table called "Recipes" and a column in that table called "ingredients". The ingredients come from an HTML input in the browser. I ask the user to separate each ingredient by hitting enter and jumping down to the next row. The problem I am having is that when I return this data on a show.blade.php page, it is returning as one long string. I have not been able to figure out how to return it as a list.

Example:

I get "oats milk bananas cinnamon maple syrup" in the part of my website where I am calling the ingredients data.

I want to get

1. Oats
2. Milk
3. Bananas
4. Cinnamon
5. Maple syrup

I am using Laravel 5.7 to build the application and I am calling {{$recipe->ingredients}}. Been messing a little bit with the PHP explode() function but with no luck. I am not very experienced so I'm sure this is not a difficult problem to solve, I just can't seem to find anything online. Perhaps I am not framing the question right?

The code to my create.blade.php file is:

```
 <div class="createRecipeBody"> 
            <fieldset>
                <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('title') }}</small>
                <label for="title">Give your creation a title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('description') }}</small>
                <label for="description">Describe your creation</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('ingredients') }}</small>
                <label for="ingredientList">List the ingredients</label>
                <textarea name="ingredients" id="ingredientList" placeholder="Please list each ingredient on a seperate line"></textarea>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                    <small class="errorMessage">{{ $errors->first('directions') }}</small>
                    <label for="ingredientList">Directions</label>
                    <textarea name="directions" id="directions" placeholder="Please list each step on a seperate line"></textarea>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="terms">
                <label class="authenticationCheck">
                    <input class="termsOfService" type="checkbox">
                    <span>
                        Public Recipe
                    </span>
                </label>

                <label class="authenticationCheck">
                    <input class="termsOfService" type="checkbox">
                    <span>Private Recipe</span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="submitRecipe" type="submit">Share your creation</button>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And this is to my show.blade.php:

```
<h2>Ingredients</h2>
                <span class="ingredients">
                    <span class="ingredientItem firstItem">
                    <span><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{$recipe->prepTime}}</span>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ingredientItem">
                    <span><i class="fas fa-concierge-bell"></i> {{$recipe->servings}}</span>
                    </span>

                    <span class="ingredientItem">
                    <span><i class="fas fa-weight"></i> {{$recipe->calories}}</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <hr>
                <p>Here's what you will need...</p>
                    <div>
                        <ol>
                            <li> {{$recipe->ingredients}}</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                <h2>Directions</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>{{$recipe->directions}}</p>

                <h2>Chef's Tip</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>This feature is not yet enabled</p>
            </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
```

Comment: When you `dd($recipe->ingredients);` do you see the line breaks ( e.g.`\n`) in the text? Can you also add the code for your blade file to your question please?

Comment: Hey @RossWilson, yes I do see the line breaks when I dd($recipe->ingredients);
I added the code for my show.blade.php and create.blade.php. Do you have any suggestions? I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```php
$string = 'apple banana cinemon pokemon';
$arr = explode(' ', $string);
array_walk($arr, function (&$item, $key) {
    $item = $key+1 . '.) ' . $item;
});
$output = implode("\n", $arr);
```

Something like this?
First I explode the string to single words.
Then I change the items to the format you asked for.
And then I'm concatenating the elements to a string.

Edit: List is now starting with 1

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the response! How would I incorporate that logic into my Controller? If I want access to $output in my blade file? :) Thanks again, really appreciate the insights!